# Приложение нужно обособить?

Tags: или, приложение, подлежащее

Один из лидеров самопровозглашенной ДНР Павел Губарев заявил, что ополченцы планируют передислоцироваться в Донецк и Горловку.

1. Павел Губарев здесь подлежащее, а _ Один из лидеров самопровозглашенной ДНР_ -  необособленное приложение(определение)?

Возможен ли такой вариант:

1. Один из лидеров самопровозглашенной ДНР, Павел Губарев, заявил, что ополченцы планируют передислоцироваться в Донецк и Горловку.

Здесь Павел Губарев - приложение, а Один из лидеров самопровозглашенной ДНР - подлежащее?

Или второй вариант - правильный, а первый - нет?
А может быть, отсутствие (наличие)запятой зависит от того, с какой интонацией произносится предложение?

Answer (score 2):

ЖЕЛАТЕЛЬНО:

(1)Павел Губарев, один из лидеров самопровозглашенной ДНР,  заявил, что ополченцы планируют передислоцироваться в Донецк и Горловку. Подлежащее + обособленное приложение.

ДРУГИЕ ВАРИАНТЫ

(2)Один из лидеров самопровозглашенной ДНР, Павел Губарев, заявил, что ополченцы планируют передислоцироваться в Донецк и Горловку.Подлежащее + обособленное приложение. Смысл примерно тот же, но интонационно предложение читается плохо.

(3)Один из лидеров самопровозглашенной ДНР Павел Губарев заявил, что ополченцы планируют передислоцироваться в Донецк и Горловку. Необособленное приложение+подлежащее. Те  же проблемы с интонацией. Необособленное приложение не должно быть слишком распространенным.

Answer (score 1):

Помнится, Розенталь писал, что если распространенное приложение стоит перед определяемым словом и характеризует его, то такое приложение не обособляется. Самый понятный пример звучит так: "Великий русский поэт А.Пушкин родился в Москве". В связи с этим приведенный Софией 3-й вариант предложения можно считать правильным.

Comment: Грамматическая структура у предложения (3) правильная, но вот наполнение не слишком удачное. У приложения "один из лидеров" бОльшая семантическая нагрузка, поэтому желательно выразить уточнение. Приложение в значительной степени распространенное, одной фразой всю конструкцию не прочитаешь. С другой стороны, оно настолько распространенное, что уже можно делить его на части (синтагмы): "Один из лидеров самопровозглашенной ДНР (короткая пауза) Павел Губарев заявил (пауза), что ополченцы планируют передислоцироваться в Донецк и Горловку". Так что Вы правы, можно использовать и этот вариант.